# Replacing lines containing a pattern with sed

Tags: sed

How can I replace a given character in a line matching a pattern with sed?

For example: I'd like to match every line beginning with a letter, and replace the newline at the end with a tab. I'm trying to do so using: `sed -e '/^[A-Z]/s/\n/\t/g'` (the lines that I'm interested in also ALWAYS end with a letter, if this can help).

Sample input

```
NAME_A
12,1
NAME_B
21,2
```

Sample output

```
NAME_A    12,1
NAME_B    21,2
```

Comment: interesting question, however I chose not to provide a solution because 'awk' would better for this. I will provide a simple awk solution if you are interested.

Comment: @don_crissti now, we should avoid telling ahelix that his question is a dupplicate from this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sed '/^[[:alpha:]]/{$!N;s/\n/       /;}' <<\DATA
NAME_A
12,1
NAME_B
21,2
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
NAME_A  12,1
NAME_B  21,2
```

That addresses lines beginning with a letter, pulls in the next if there is one, and substitutes a tab character for the newline.

*note that the `s/\n/<tab>/` bit contains a literal tab character here, though some `sed`s might also support the `\t` escape in its place*

To handle a recursive situation you need to make it a little more robust, like this:

```
sed '$!N;/^[[:alpha:]].*\n[^[:alpha:]]/s/\n/    /;P;D' <<\DATA
NAME_A
NAME_B
12,1  
NAME_C
21,2
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
NAME_A
NAME_B  12,1
NAME_C  21,2
```

That slides through a data set always one line ahead. If two `^[[:alpha:]]` lines occur one after the other, it does not mistakenly replace the newline, as you can see.

Comment: please also upvote the question - it is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n\([^[:alpha:]]\)/ \1/;ta' -e 'P;D'
```

This append current line to previous line if it not start with alphabeta.

**Updated**

A solution by @mikerserv after our discussion:

```
sed ':a
/^[[:alpha:]]/{$!N;/\n[^[:alpha:]]/!ba;s/\(.*\)\n/\1\t/}
' file
```

**Explanation**

> On a line that starts with an alphabetic character, it pulls in the
>   next if there is one, then, if it can address a newline followed
>   by a non-alphabetic character, it selects everything in pattern 
>   space up to the last newline there and does a substitute on it - changing 
>   the last new line to a tab. But if not it branches back and tries again.

Comment: But what if the previous line didn't start with [[:alpha:]]?

Comment: This will concat consecutive lines does not start with [[:alpha:]].