# Replace a string containing newline characters

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, newlines

With the `bash` shell, in a file with rows like the following ones

```
first "line"
<second>line and so on
```

I would like to replace one or more occurrences of `"line"\n<second>` with `other characters` and obtain each time:

```
first other characters line and so on
```

So I have to replace a string both with special characters such as `"` and `<` and with a newline character.

After searching between the other answers, I found that `sed` can accept newlines in the right-hand side of the command (so, the `other characters` string), but not in the left.

Is there a way (simpler than [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147149/replacing-lines-containing-a-pattern-with-sed)) to obtain this result with `sed` or `grep`?

Comment: are you working w/ a mac? the `\n`ewline statement you make is why i ask. people seldom ask if they can do `s//\n/` as you can with GNU `sed`, though most other `sed`s will reject that escape on the right hand side. still, the `\n` escape will work on the left in any POSIX `sed` and you can portably translate them like `y/c/\n/` though it will have the same effect as `s/c/\n/g` and so isnt always as useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Three different `sed` commands:

```
sed '$!N;s/"[^"]*"\n<[^>]*>/other characters /;P;D'

sed -e :n -e '$!N;s/"[^"]*"\n<[^>]*>/other characters /;tn'

sed -e :n -e '$!N;/"$/{$!bn' -e '};s/"[^"]*"\n<[^>]*>/other characters /g'
```

They all three build on the basic `s///`ubstitution command:

```
s/"[^"]*"\n<[^>]*>/other characters /
```

They also all try to take care in their handling of the last line, as `sed`s tend to differ on their output in edge cases. This is the meaning of `$!` which is an address matching every line that is `!`not the `$`last.

They also all use the `N`ext command to append the next input line to pattern space following a `\n`ewline character. Anyone who has been `sed`ing for a while will have learned to rely on the `\n`ewline character - because the only way to get one is to explicitly put it there.

All three make some attempt to read in as little input as possible before taking action - `sed` acts as soon as it might and needn't read in an entire input file before doing so.

Though they do all `N`, they all three differ in their methods of recursion.

#### First Command

The first command employs a very simple `N;P;D` loop. These three commands are built-in to any POSIX-compatible `sed` and they complement one another nicely.

- `N` - as already mentioned, appends the `N`ext input line to pattern-space following an inserted `\n`ewline delimiter.
- `P` - like `p`; it `P`rints pattern-space - but only up-to the first occurring `\n`ewline character. And so, given the following input/command:

  - `printf %s\\n one two | sed '$!N;P;d'`
- `sed` `P`rints only *one*. However, with...
- `D` - like `d`; it `D`eletes pattern-space and begins another line-cycle. *Unlike* `d`, `D` deletes only up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern-space. If there is more in pattern-space following `\n`ewline character, `sed` begins the next line cycle with what remains. If the `d` in the previous example were replaced with a `D`, for example, `sed` would `P`rint both *one* and *two*.

This command recurses only for lines which *do not* match the `s///`ubstitution statement. Because the `s///`ubstitution removes the `\n`ewline added with `N`, there is never anything remaining when `sed` `D`eletes pattern-space.

Tests could be done to apply the `P` and/or `D` selectively, but there are other commands which fit better with that strategy. Because the recursion is implemented to handle consecutive lines which match only *part* of the replacement rule, consecutive sequences of lines matching *both ends* of the `s///`ubstitution do not work well.:

Given this input:

```
first "line"
<second>"line"
<second>"line"
<second>line and so on
```

...it prints...

```
first other characters "line"
<second>other characters line and so on
```

It does, however, handle

```
first "line"
second "line"
<second>line
```

...just fine.

#### Second Command

This command is very similar to the third. Both employ a `:b`ranch/`t`est label *(as is also demonstrated in Joeseph R.'s answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163473/52934))* and recurse back to it given certain conditions.

- `-e :n -e` - portable `sed` scripts will delimit a `:`label definition with either a `\n`ewline or a new inline `-e`xecution statement.

  - `:n` - defines a label named `n`. This can be returned to at any time with either `bn` or `tn`.
- `tn` - the `t`est command returns to a specified label *(or, if none is provided, quits the script for the current line-cycle)* if any `s///`ubstitution since either the label was defined or since it was last called `t`ests successful.

In this command the recursion occurs for the matching lines. If `sed` successfully replaces the pattern with *other characters*, `sed` returns to the `:n` label and tries again. If a `s///`ubstitution is not performed `sed` autoprints pattern-space and begins the next line-cycle.

This tends to handle consecutive sequences better. Where the last one failed, this prints:

```
first other characters other characters other characters line and so on
```

#### Third Command

As mentioned, the logic here is very similar to the last, but the test is more explicit.

- `/"$/bn` - this is `sed`'s test. Because the `b`ranch command is a function of this address, `sed` will only `b`ranch back to `:n` after a `\n`ewline is appended and pattern-space still ends with a `"` double-quote.

There is as little done between `N` and `b` as possible - in this way `sed` can very quickly gather exactly as much input as necessary to ensure that the following line cannot match your rule. The `s///`ubstitution differs here in that it employs the `g`lobal flag - and so it will do all necessary replacements at once. Given identical input this command outputs identically to the last.

Comment: Sorry for the trivial question, but what is the meaning of `DATA` and how do you receive the text input?

Comment: @BowPark - In this example `<<\DATA\ntext input\nDATA\n` is baked in, but that is only text handed to `sed` by the shell in a [here document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html). It would work as well like `sed 'script' filename` or `process that writes to stdout | sed 'script'`. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you! Why without `D` every modified line is double? (You used it as it is necessary; maybe I don't know `sed` very well)

Comment: @BowPark - you get doubles when omitting the `D` because `D` otherwise `D`eletes from output what you now see doubled. I have just made an edit - and I may expand on that as well soon.

Comment: @BowPark - ok, I've updated it and provided options. It might be a little easier to read/understand now. I also explicitly addressed the `D` thing.

Answer (score 9):

Well, I can think of a couple of simple ways but neither involves `grep` (which doesn't do substitutions anyway) or `sed`.

1. Perl

   To replace *each* occurrence of `"line"\n<second>` with `other characters`, use:

   ```
   $ perl -00pe 's/"line"\n<second>/other characters /g' file
   first other characters line and so on
   ```

   Or, to treat multiple, consecutive occurrences of `"line"\n<second>` as one, and replace all of them with a single `other characters`, use:

   ```
   perl -00pe 's/(?:"line"\n<second>)+/other characters /g' file
   ```

   **Example:**

   ```
   $ cat file
   first "line"
   <second>"line"
   <second>"line"
   <second>line and so on
   $ perl -00pe 's/(?:"line"\n<second>)+/other characters /g' file
   first other characters line and so on
   ```

   The `-00` causes Perl to read the file in "paragraph mode" which means that "lines" are defined by `\n\n` instead of `\n`, essentially, each paragraph is treated as a line. The substitution therefore matches across a newline.
2. awk

   ```
   $  awk -v RS="\n\n" -v ORS="" '{
         sub(/"line"\n<second>/,"other characters ", $0)
         print;
       }' file 
   first other characters line and so on
   ```

   The same basic idea, we set the record separator (`RS`) to `\n\n` to slurp the whole file, then the output record separator to nothing (otherwise an extra newline is printed) and then use the `sub()` function to make the replacement.

Comment: @mikeserv? Which one? The second is supposed to, the OP said they want "to replace one or more occurrences of", so eating the paragraph might well be what they expect.

Comment: very good point. I guess I focused more on *and obtain each time*, but I guess it is not clear if that should be one replacement per occurrence or one replacement per sequence of occurrences... @BowPark?

Comment: It is needed one replacement per occurrence.

Comment: @BowPark OK, then the first perl approach or the awk should both work. Don't they give you the desired output?

Comment: It works, thank you, but the third line with `awk` should be `print;}' file`. I need to avoid Perl and to preferably use `sed`, anyway you suggested good alternatives.

Comment: Should we do : `perl -00pe 's/"line"\n<second>/other characters /g' file > file` to update the file?

Comment: @alper no! That will empty the file because `> file` (which clears the contents of `file`) will be run before the perl script. If you want to chage the original file, use `perl -i -00pe '...' file`. The `-i` means "edit the file in place". You can also use `-i.bak` to keep a copy of the original with the extension `.bak`.

Answer (score 6):

read the whole file and do a global replacement:

```
sed -n 'H; ${x; s/"line"\n<second>/other characters /g; p}' <<END
first "line"
<second> line followed by "line"
<second> and last
END
```

```
first other characters  line followed by other characters  and last
```

Comment: Yes. It works, but what if I have multiple occurrences?

Comment: Huh, right. Fixed

Comment: sorry to nitpick again, but `${cmds}` is GNU-specific - most other `sed`s will require a `\n`ewline or an `-e` break between `p` and `}`. You can avoid the brackets altogether - and portably - and even avoid inserting an extra `\n`ewline character on the first line like: `sed 'H;1h;$!d;x;s/"line"\n<second>/other characters /g'`

Comment: I tested it and it seems not portable. It prints an extra new-line at the beginning of the output, but the result is correct on GNU.

Comment: To remove the leading newline: `sed -n '1{h;n};H; ${x; s/"line"\n<second>/other characters /g; p}'` -- however this is getting unmaintainable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a variant on [glenn's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163444/26909) that will work if you have multiple consecutive occurrences (works with GNU `sed` only):

```
sed ':x /"line"/N;s/"line"\n<second>/other characters/;/"line"/bx' your_file
```

The `:x` is just a label for branching. Basically, what this does, is that it checks the line after substitution and if it still matches `"line"`, it branches back to the `:x` label (that's what `bx` does)  and adds another line to the buffer and starts processing it.

Comment: @mikeserv Please be specific about what you mean. It worked for me.

Comment: @mikeserv I'm sorry, I really don't know what you're talking about. I copied the above code line back into my terminal and it worked correctly.

Comment: retracted - this does apparently work in GNU `sed` which takes its non-POSIX label handling far enough to accept a space as a delimiter for label declaration. You should note though, that any other `sed` will fail there - and will fail for `N`. GNU `sed` breaks POSIX guidelines to print pattern-space before quitting on a `N` on the last line, but POSIX makes it clear that if an `N` command is read on the last line *nothing* should be printed.

Comment: If you edit the post to specify GNU I will reverse my vote and delete these comments. Also, it might be worth learning about GNU's `v` command which breaks in every other `sed` but is a no-op in GNU versions 4 and greater.

Comment: @mikeserv Thanks for the comments. I edited the post. Please don't delete your comments as they may benefit someone else.

Comment: in that case I will offer one more - this can be done portably like: `sed -e :x -e '/"line"/{$!N' -e '};s/"line"\n<second>/other characters/;/"line"/bx'`.