# Adding a new column using information from subheadings

Tags: sed, awk

[Replacing lines containing a pattern with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147149/replacing-lines-containing-a-pattern-with-sed)

Thanks to @don_crissti and @Archemar. I reckon my question is not a duplication of the above question.

So here is an example of input. **Edit:** All sections have values. I've added another complexity to the subheading (I should have done that).

```
DATA1

NAME: A (X)
12,1
13,2
14,4

NAME: B (X)
21,2
22,3

NAME: C (X)
24,4
```

The desired output should look like

```
DATA1

A    12,1
A    13,2
A    14,4

B    21,2
B    22,3

C    24,4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your output separator is 4 spaces, so that's what this example uses - change it to what ever you need, eg for a TAB, `OFS="\t"`

```
awk 'NR==1 || NF==0 {print; next}  # main heading and blank lines 
     $1=="NAME:" {name=$2; next}   # section name/header
     {print name, $1}              # data lines
    ' OFS="    " file
```

Output:

```
DATA1

A    12,1
A    13,2
A    14,4

B    21,2
B    22,3

C    24,4
```

Comment: You can combine the 1st and 3rd conditions: `NR==1 || NF==0 {print; next}`

Comment: Thanks @glennjackman, especially for the `==`,  and the reminder to use the number of fields

Answer (score 2):

Here's sed. I don't recommend it

```
sed -n '
    1 {p; n}
    /^[[:blank:]]*$/ {p; n}
    /^NAME: \+/ {s///; h; n}
    {H; g; s/\n/ /; p; s/ .*//; h}
' file
```

It does just what Peter's awk command does, except sed has only one variable: the hold space.

Comment: Since the OP changed the format of the Input data, it needs an additional `'s/ .*//; ` before `h; n}` (or similar).